# How to put a paragraph left in a list (ToC)

Tags: table-of-contents, indentation, paragraphs, abnt

I'm using `\paragraph` to simulate a `\subsubsubsection` but my ToC is appearing with this paragraph spacing. Does anyone know how to remove this space leaving the left?

[image]

Using this code:

```
\paragraph{BMP085}
```

Configurations:

```
%=======================================================================
% ------------------------------------------------------------------------
% ------------------------------------------------------------------------
% abnTeX2: Modelo de Trabalho Academico  em conformidade com 
% ABNT NBR 14724:2011: Informacao e documentacao - Trabalhos academicos
% ------------------------------------------------------------------------
%Customização Unoesc
% ------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Edição: TexStudio
% Codificação: UTF-8
% LaTeX:  abnTeX2
%
%=======================================================================

\documentclass[
    % -- opções da classe memoir --
    12pt,               % tamanho da fonte  
    oneside,          % não imprimir em verso e anverso, oposto do twoside 
    a4paper,            % tamanho do papel. 
    % -- opções da classe abntex2 --
    chapter=TITLE,      % títulos de capítulos convertidos em letras maiúsculas
    section=TITLE,      % títulos de seções convertidos em letras maiúsculas
    subsection=TITLE,   % títulos de subseções convertidos em letras maiúsculas
    %subsubsection=TITLE,% títulos de subsubseções convertidos em letras maiúsculas
    % -- opções do pacote babel --
    english,            % idioma adicional para hifenização
    brazil,         % o último idioma é o principal do documento
    sumario=tradicional 
    ]{abntex2-unoesc}

%\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption} % Serve para centralizar caption
\usepackage{float}  

\include{config_inicial}

%----Include da capa é fora do documento 
\include{pretextuais/capa}
%---

\begin{document}
% Retira espaço extra obsoleto entre as frases.
\frenchspacing 

% ----------------------------------------------------------
% ELEMENTOS PRÉ-TEXTUAIS
% ----------------------------------------------------------

%--- CAPA ----
\imprimircapa

% --- FOLHA DE ROSTO
\imprimirfolhaderosto
% \imprimirfolhaderosto* (o * indica que haverá a ficha bibliográfica)

% Inserir FOLHA DE APROVAÇÃO
\include{pretextuais/folhadeaprovacao}

% lista de ilustrações
\pdfbookmark[0]{\listfigurename}{lof}
\listoffigures*
\cleardoublepage
% ---

% LISTA DE TABELAS
%\pdfbookmark[0]{\listtablename}{lot}
%\listoftables*
%\cleardoublepage  %-- força proxima pagina

% SUMARIO
\pdfbookmark[0]{\contentsname}{toc}
\tableofcontents*
\cleardoublepage

% ------------------------------------------------------
% ELEMENTOS TEXTUAIS
% ------------------------------------------------------
\textual
% INTRODUÇÃO
\include{conteudo/introducao}

%Revisão
\include{conteudo/revisao_bibliografica}

% ----------------------------------------------------------
% ELEMENTOS PÓS-TEXTUAIS
% ----------------------------------------------------------
\postextual

% ----------------------------------------------------------
% Referências bibliográficas
% ----------------------------------------------------------

\bibliography{referencias}

%---------------------------------------------------------------------
% INDICE REMISSIVO
%---------------------------------------------------------------------

\printindex
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The class you're using [`abntex2-unoesc.cls`](https://github.com/jonasalessi/abntex2-unoesc/tree/master/LatexUnoesc) ultimately relies on [`memoir`](http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir). So, changes to the ToC can be made using `memoir`-specific configurations.

All that is needed is to replace the `\paragraph` indent in the ToC through

```
\setlength{\cftparagraphindent}{0pt}
```

`\subparagraph`s are not included in the ToC by default.

[image]

```
\documentclass[
    % -- opções da classe memoir --
    12pt,               % tamanho da fonte  
    oneside,          % não imprimir em verso e anverso, oposto do twoside 
    a4paper,            % tamanho do papel. 
    % -- opções da classe abntex2 --
    chapter=TITLE,      % títulos de capítulos convertidos em letras maiúsculas
    section=TITLE,      % títulos de seções convertidos em letras maiúsculas
    subsection=TITLE,   % títulos de subseções convertidos em letras maiúsculas
    %subsubsection=TITLE,% títulos de subsubseções convertidos em letras maiúsculas
    % -- opções do pacote babel --
    english,            % idioma adicional para hifenização
    brazil,         % o último idioma é o principal do documento
    sumario=tradicional 
    ]{abntex2-unoesc}

\input{config_inicial}

\setlength{\cftparagraphindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{A chapter}
\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\subsubsection{A subsubsection}
\paragraph{A paragraph}

\end{document}
```